How to manage tons of components in our self-host gitlab?
We have numerous components organized in our GitLab repository by functionality. For instance, all Maven-related components, such as maven_base, maven_set_version, and maven_package, are stored in the same repository.
However, when it comes to upgrades(add a version tag), we face an issue: all components are upgraded even if some of them haven't changed.
Here is the structure of our components

Are there best practices for managing this situation?
